# How can I set breakpoints in a Cucumber Java .feature file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, karate

Is there a way to include a breakpoint in the Intellij or in the Karate .feature file.
This would be very useful because debugging the code it is easier to find the errors and not need to have to run all the code at all times to view logs.

Comment: and maybe you can vote for this, or contribute code: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243704